# Loading custom font from resources for label

Tags: c#

I am trying to use a custom font for my WinForm application  (Segoe UI Light font to be exact) and I have added it into my resources, as I research the internet all I find is code to load it from a file path, and other ways outside the application, I need a way to load it inside the application in case I give it to someone and they don't have it in the path I do, is there a way to do it from inside from the resources? Thanks, I have been researching all day but no hope.

I tried a PrivatwFontCollection but it only allos me to add from a file path also.

> For the person who said it was duplicate, that code is broke and wont
>   work on my app, the line `byte[] fontdata = new
>   byte[fontStream.Length];` throw an error saying
>
> An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'
>   occurred in HR.exe
>
> Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.

Comment: So, fontStream is null - thus fontstream.Length is not valid (null pointer).

Comment: Yes.. so I want another solution.